# How to decide what IP to use on WS server in node js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a WebSocket Server, but the problem is that it uses `0.0.0.0` while I want it to use `127.0.0.1`, how may I select what IP Address it should use?

This is my code

```
var c               = require('chalk'),
    log             = require('../packages/log.js'),
    _crypto         = require('../packages/crypto.js'),
    WebSocket       = require('ws');

var ws = new WebSocket.Server({port:88,ip:'127.0.0.1'});

ws.on ('connection', connection => {
    connection.on('message', msg => {

    });
    connection.send('Hello');
});
```

But it still uses `0.0.0.0`. So how to determine the IP Address to use?

Comment: What do you mean: "it uses 0.0.0.0"?

Comment: It uses `0.0.0.0` as the DNS to the WebSocket Server

Comment: "Uses as the DNS"?  What does that mean?  0.0.0.0 is not a DNS name.  Are you saying that you can't connect to it with `localhost` or with `127.0.0.1`?  Sorry, but your question is simply not clear what the problem is.  Perhaps if you show the code to connect to it that doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try just leaving the IP address out of the server initialization entirely?  Then, it should allow both 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

Comment: @robertklep's answer mentions how it can be done with the reference to the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to bind the server to a specific host, you can use this:

```
var ws = new WebSocket.Server({ port : 88, host : '127.0.0.1' });
```

Documented [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I was really mixed up for a sec with the addition of your IP. I am not sure why you did that, but that seems to be the problem here.

If you are using websocket (with no TLS) the following is the original call.

`let WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
let ws = new WebSocketServer({port: Port Number Here});`

Then when you need it in the file .. just an example

```
ws.on('connection', function (ws) {
    console.log('Server WebSocket was connected.');

    //  Add the listener for that particular websocket connection instance.
    ws.on('message', function (data) {
       //code  goes here for what you need
 });

    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('websocket connection closed!');
    });

});
```